# PowerShell Script Running Issues - Has to be ran twice in ISE and does not work when executed from file explorer location

Tags: powershell

I'm currently experiencing some problems with importing/editing existing registry keys into a printer driver location.

After some searching I found that `Set-ItemProperty` is the exact thing I need to rewrite subkey areas within the registry, however, I've had a lot of trouble running it.

When the code is put directly into the PowerShell console it works perfectly and updates the file in just the way I want it to.

When the code is open and ran in Powershell ISE it has to run several times consecutively (spammed around 3 times) for it works.

When the code is ran from its PS1 file from its file explorer location (C:\user\RW Sandbox\Documents\Printerscripts) then it doesn't work at all, regardless of whether or not I've spammed the run invocation.

This is the code I was using (although mine includes a lot more hex than this example):

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Xerox\PrinterDriver\V5.0\Xerox Global Print Driver PCL6\DeviceSettings" -Name "CachedXrxDeviceSettings" -Type "binary" -Value ([byte[]](0x10,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x07,0x20,0x2b,0x16,0x58,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x4d,0x53,0x43,0x46,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x70,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x2c,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03))
```

Within the PowerShell, the execution policy is currently unrestricted as initially, I believed that this might have been a permission issue.

Comment: Could it be that in some cases the registry value does not yet exist? Test for that and if the value exists use `Set-ItemProperty`, otherwise `New-ItemProperty`

Comment: What do you mean run from file explorer?  You have a shortcut that runs `powershell -file script.ps1`?  Simply doubleclicking on a ps1 file won't run it.

Comment: Theo - the registry definitely exists as it come pre installed with the printer driver.

Comment: js2010 by file explorer I mean I'm going into my files, right clicking the .ps1 file and "running as powershell", a power shell terminal briefly pops up and then disapears with no visible errors occurring. (however the code within the script does not activate)

Comment: @RobWilson - please add a `pause` to the end of the script so you can see what is happening. you may also want to add `Start-Transcript` to the beginning & the stop version to the end of your code.

Comment: If it executes the second time, it suggests that there may be a prerequisite Missing. +1 for the previous comment - add a pause at the end of the script and put in a number of write-host statements so you can see where the problem may be